# QTableview checkitems, get value from corresponding second column

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two questions regarding `QTableView`.

1. How to make the QTable editable only for second column value, and read only for first column?
2. How to get the index of the checked item, so that you can get the value of the second column corresponding to the checked item?

   ```
   from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

   class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           super().__init__(parent=parent)

           # selected items
           self.selected = []
           self.no       = []

           self.tableModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
           self.tableModel.itemChanged.connect(self.itemChanged)
           # 
           item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem("file#1")
           item1.setCheckable(True)
           no1 = QtGui.QStandardItem("5.0")
           self.tableModel.appendRow([item1, no1])
           # 
           item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("file#2")
           item2.setCheckable(True)
           no2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("23.0")
           self.tableModel.appendRow([item2, no2])

           self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
           self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

           self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
           self.tableView.setModel(self.tableModel)
           self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)

           "First Question"
           """How to make table only editable second column, not firts:
              ex. can edit 23.0 or 5.0, but read only file names?
           """        

       def itemChanged(self, item):
           if item.checkState() != 0:
               if not item.text() in self.selected:
                   self.selected.append(item.text())
           else:
               if item.text() in self.selected:
                   self.selected.remove(item.text())

           print(self.selected)

           "Second Question"
           """How to get item checked index and to get the second column value:
              ex. file#2 has 23.0?
           """

           self.no.append(second column value) ****?
           print(self.no)

   def main():
       app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

       mytable = MyWidget()
       mytable.show()
       app.exec_()

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to make the QTable editable only for second column value, and read only for first column?**

There are several solutions to make the items of an entire column readonly/editable.

- modify flags, it is not necessary to implement a custom model as suggested by the [PyThagoras's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63202556/6622587) since the QStandardItemModel model allows modifying them:

  ```
  # To make them editable:
  item.setEditable(True)
  # or
  # item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)

  # To make them readonly:
  item.setEditable(False)
  # or
  # item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
  ```
- Use the editor of the delegate, since the QStandardItemModel model is editable by default so it is only enough to establish that column 0 is non-editable and for this you should not generate an editor:

  ```
  class ReadOnlyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
      def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
          return
  ```

  ```
  delegate = ReadOnlyDelegate(self.tableView)
  self.tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
  ```

I prefer the second option since by default it establishes that the first column is readonly.

**How to get the index of the checked item, so that you can get the value of the second column corresponding to the checked item?**

The generic method is to access the father and then the son who is in the same row but in the second column:

```
parent_item = item.parent()
if parent_item is not None:
    second_item = parent_item.child(item.row(), 1)
else:
    second_item = item.model().item(item.row(), 1)
print(second_item.text())
```

But in your case it can be simplified to:

```
second_item = self.tableModel.item(item.row(), 1)
print(second_item.text())
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the elaboration

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate questions. I believe you should ask them separately and modify your question accordingly.

**For your first question: How to make a column READ_ONLY?**

For that, you have to define your own `QAbstractTableModel` `class` to define a method called `flags`. Those flags will allow you to change the properties of the cells as you desire. Then, you have to pass your new `QAbstractTableModel` to a `QTableView` and set it as the new model (It is like the backend of the `QTableView`)

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication


class ParametersTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ParametersTableModel, self).__init__()
        self.headerText = ["Parameter 1", "Parameter 2"]
        self.data = [[1, 2], [1, 2]]

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.data)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.headerText)

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return self.headerText[col]

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            return self.data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        else:
            if index.column() == 1:
                return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
            else:
                return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    tableModel = ParametersTableModel()
    tableView = QTableView()
    tableView.setModel(tableModel)
    tableView.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can always check Qt's documentation for more in-depth insight.
[QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html),
[QAbstractTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html)